# Integer partition weighted minimum

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Given a non-negative integer $n$ and a positive real weight vector $w$ with dimension $m$, partition $n$ into a length-$m$ non-negative integer vector that sums to $n$ (call it $v$) such that $w\cdot v$ is the smallest. There maybe several partitions, and we only want the value of $w\cdot v$.

Seems like this problem can use a greedy algorithm to solve. From a target vector for $n-1$, we add 1 to each entry, and find the minimum among those $m$ vectors. but I don't think it's correct. The intuition is that it might add "over" the minimum. That is, there exists another partition not yielded by the add 1 procedure that falls in between the "minimum" of $n-1$ produced by this greedy algorithm and that of $n$ produced by this greedy algorithm. Can anyone prove if this is correct or incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that the elements of `w` are non-decreasing. Let `v` be a `m`-vector whose values are non-negative integers that sum to `n`. Then the smallest inner product of `v` and `w` is achieved by setting `v[0] = n` and `v[i] = 0` for `i > 0`.

This is easy to prove. Suppose `v` is any other vector with `v[i] > 0` for some `i > 0`. Then we can increase `v[0]` by `v[i]` and reduce `v[i]` to zero. The elements of `v` will still sum to `n` and the inner product of `v` and `w` will be reduced by `w[i] - w[0] >= 0`.